# Sharing user login between Blazor WebServer and ASP.NET Core API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.0

I am building a service-oriented system for personal use (plus few friends may have limited access as well) - the aim is to have a dashboard for controlling my apps running on various machines such as Raspberry Pis (and potentially to be expanded to a VPS or few in future).

The architecture itself is pretty simple. For authentication I want to use AWS Cognito. Services would communicate with WebAPI (and potentially with eachother) using gRPC within a VPN, and dashboard would be served by Blazor server-side (may move to Blazor WASM Hosted model if I find a need for it). Each of the processes may or may not be on the same machine as any other (depending on the purpose). Blazor server may or may not run within VPN (I might want to move it to a separate web hosting later).

I created a simple diagram to visualize it:
[image]

---

The problem comes with authentication. I want to have Blazor server-side and API as a separate processes (for now they're going to run on the same machine, but I may want to move it elsewhere eventually). **Ideally authentication should be handled by API, so authentication is client-agnostic, and the API can use it to verify if the logged in user can perform an action** - which by itself is simple.

However, **I want Blazor server to use and validate that token as well** in order to determine what to display to the user. I want to do with the least amount of calls possible - ideally avoiding querying API for every 'should I display it or not?' choice.

I could easily do it by sacrificing possibility to move API elsewhere, and just merge Blazor Server and API Gateway into one project. For my current purpose it would be enough, but it's not an ideal solution, so first I want to look into how could I achieve my original vision.

---

How could I achieve this (with minimal amount of Blazor server to API queries)?

I was googling for solution a lot, but so far only found either examples of using Blazor server and API as one project, or using client-side calls to API directly.

Thank you good folks in advance.

Comment: Damn. I need to know this as well. Did you make any progress with it so far?

Comment: Any progress on this?